# Occationally MVC Postback data are wrongly formatted in IE 8,7,6

Tags: model-view-controller, internet-explorer, post, asp.net-mvc-4

About 5% of our visitors are not able to post a webform with success. The data returned (attributes) in the controller are empty. If I look in the Request.Form collection I see that it has a key with this value:

```
Key:-----------------------------7dc123b1036c 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name
Value:"mac" BByYu99xL2QUkiC_y-JuZ2a3Ut6ZuUC781 -----------------------------7dc123b1036c--
```

Im only sending one hidden field in this postback and its named "mac". Any ideas why this is returned in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I removed encrypt tag of "multipart/form-data" and suddenly IE is posting just fine.